# ¿Remover un objeto de la coleccion en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

tengo lo siguiente, estoy obteniendo todos los clientes que pertenecen a un usuario con eloquent, estos clientes los muestro en un select en la vista blade, mi problema es que en la tabla clientes hay un campo que me especifica si el cliente ya esta asignado o no, necesito remover de la coleccion de clientes los que ya estan asignados, para que en la vista blade solo me muestre los que no estan asignados lo estoy intentando de la siguiente forma:

```
public function getClients()
    {
        //Con esto obtenemos todos los clientes que pertenezcan al usuario autenticado
        $client = Auth::user()->clients()->get();

        foreach ($client as $clients) {
            if ($clients->community =='asigned' && $clients->account_director == 'asigned') {
                $client->pull($clients);
            }

        }

        dd($client);

        return $client;
    }
```

pero obtengo este error array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer", ¿de que manera podría remover de la colección los clientes que ya están asignados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si entiendo bien lo que necesitas es:

> "remover de la coleccion de clientes los que ya estan
>   asignados"

Me confunde un poco el codigo que pusiste pero creo que lo que tenés que hacer es:

```
public function getClients()
{
    $clients = Auth::user()->clients->where('community', '!=', 'asigned')
                                    ->where('account_director', '!=', 'asigned');

    return $clients;
}
```

Espero mi solución te sea de ayuda.

Comment: buena respuesta, pero a veces los que ven respuestas copian y pegan las respuestas y si no les funciona no se dan cuenta por que.?¿. Asi que te recomiendo agregar `->get()` al final de tu consulta eloquent, o funciona asi?

Comment: Uy si me olvidé. Ya lo agrego.

Comment: Me quedé pensando. En realidad el get() no deberia ir porque no es un query sino que en este caso el `where` es el `where` de las [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-where).

Comment: el `get()` es obligatoria, a menos que se utilice `->first()` o `->all()` y precisamente son las collecions las que hacen uso de este, caso contrario solo te retornaria el `Builder`

Comment: es que si esta bien hecha la relacion el get ya está hecho cuando hacés `Auth::user()->clients`. Acá ya te lista todos los clientes del usuario autenticado y en una colección, entonces despues lo manejamos coo una collection haciendo los where.  
La verdad que yo no tengo ese codigo pero hice una prueba en una de mis apps y si ponés el get() te va a tirar un error. El error sería algo como `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Comment: tienes razon. fue mi error de novato.

Comment: Igual de entrada me hiciste dudar jaja

Comment: No era lo que esperaba, pero me funciono y esta es la solución que voy a aplicar, muchas gracias maru. habia visto otra manera diferente a usar una consulta con where, que era removiendo datos de la coleccion usando forget o pull pero no logre plantearlo de la manera correcta, asi que me quedo con tu solucion. Gracias